# Select a value from a row based on a date switch row

Tags: excel-formula

I have a date switch row (Row 7) that goes False False False False True False False etc.
I want to look along the row, find the True, and then select the value in the same column but in a different row (row 70).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

use this formula:

```
=INDEX(A$70:$G$70,1,MATCH(TRUE,$A$7:$G$7,0))
```

where:

`A$70:$G$70` is the *target range* *(row 70)*

`$A$7:$G$7` is the *source range* *(row 7)*

`MATCH(TRUE,$A$7:$G$7,0)` gives the position *(column number)* of the first occurrence of `TRUE` in the *source range*

`INDEX(A$70:$G$70,0,X)` retrieves the value in row `1` column `X` *(value returned by `MATCH`)* from the *target range*